# What are these battery power connectors called?

Tags: batteries, connector, contact, power-connector

I'm trying to source some battery contact connectors for sliding straight metal strips into.  They're the sort of thing that are used in power tool batteries, but I want to use them for a different project.

[image: Example Photo 1]

[image: Example Photo 2]

Can anyone tell me what these are called and any example part numbers / links?  I've tried searching for things like "battery contact", "power tool battery contact" and a few similar terms, but have drawn a blank so far.

For reference, the ones in the photo came from a [Makita Battery Case Kit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002025023621.html) that you can buy to make DIY power tool batteries.

Comment: "What are these connectors?" is allowed, but "Where can I get them?" isn't.

Comment: @user253751 - okay: I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: Every OEM wants to protect it's proprietary charger interface with some custom parts and physical uniqueness.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: You might find bus bar connectors or some kinds of fuse clips as substitutes.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The ones I photographed were off a copy of the Makita battery from a Chinese supplier.  I've found several suppliers of these "Battery Kits", all of which include the same connector.  Given they seem to have slightly different versions of the battery connector PCB, I assume they're from different manufacturers (and probably not Makita).  Therefore I assume that the connectors can be bought.  I don't know for certain though.

Comment: I can  buy clone connectors too but $300 MOQ.  Try AUK if you have some volume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are "spring leaf socket PCB terminals". The ones in your pictures are custom made. You can buy similar ones off-the-shelf:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003287167688.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra

[image] {AliExpress}

Comment: One , two or three pairs of contacts....

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!