# Where to find battery pack contacts

Tags: batteries, pcb, connector, wire, wire-terminals

[image]

So i need those metral spring terminals like those on this battery pcb, can someone help to find those, or whats called at least.. THANKS

Comment: Does [THIS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616870/what-are-these-battery-power-connectors-called) answer your question?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=battery+blade+contacts&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: i already saw that post, but they are not exectly the same also i need alot thos contacts maybe 500-1000 and those price are 1$ for only 3.

Comment: @BorisIlic no matter how we turn it, your question is literally about places to buy something - and these questions are explicitly off-topic here. So, what remains on-topic is "what are they called?" and that's answered in the other question that you say you've already read!

Comment: @jsotola. Your search for "battery blade contacts" does not return any result for your type of contact.  A better search is for ["power tool" battery connector socket contacts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22power+tool%22+battery+connector+socket+contacts)

Answer (score 0):

They are "spring leaf socket PCB terminals". The ones in your pictures are custom made. You can buy similar ones off-the-shelf:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003287167688.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2fra

[image] {AliExpress}